# Diferença padrões Transaction script e Domain model?

Tags: design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Gostaria de saber a diferença conceitual e de implementação entre essas duas camadas utilizadas na camada de negocio.

Pra mim o padrão Transaction script lembra muito o padrão facade, mas ele fala em procedimentos: *Organiza lógica de negócio em **procedimentos**, no qual cada procedimento realiza uma requisição da camada de apresentação* e isso acaba sempre gerando confusão.

Um ponto importante que eu noto entre esses dois padrões Transaction script e Domain model, é que a camada de cima (apresentação) sempre conversa com um único objeto, isso em minha visão pode acabar gerando um acoplamento, estou certo?